# Changing legend window in Carto new editor?

Tags: carto, legend

I have created a map with an automatic legend window.

I'd like to move the window to the lower right corner.

I tried to edit the CSS but I cannot figure out how to do with the new editor.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the position of the legend element in CARTO Builder.